Operator norm bound on the BCH formula
Let X and Y be two Hermitian matrices. Let $Z$ be the hermitian matrix given by the BCH formula, which is such that $e^{iX} e^{-iY} = e^{-i Z}$. (An explicit expression of $Z$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$ can be found e.g. on Wikipedia)
What is an upper bound on $\| Z - (Y-X) \|$ in operator norm? I would like to have an upper bound in terms of $\|Y-X\|$ and of the operator norms of X and Y. For example, I would like to derive a bound like $\| Z - (Y-X) \|\le C \|Y-X\|$ where $C$ is some function of $\|X\|$ and $\|Y\|$.
I've tried to use triangle inequality and sub-additivity of the operator norm, but I am not able to derive an explicit upper bound. Do you how to solve this problem? Thank you very much!
